# append row values from one df to another if no duplicates in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, append

I have theses two dfs

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'pupil': ["sarah", "john", "fred"],
                  'class': ["1a", "1a", "1a"]})


df2 = pd.DataFrame({'pupil_mixed': ["sarah", "john", "lex"],
                  'class': ["1a", "1c", "1a"]})
```

I want to append the row values from the column "pupil_mixed" from df2
to the column "pupil" in df1 if the values are no duplicates

desired outcome:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'pupil': ["sarah", "john", "fred", 'lex'],
                  'class': ["1a", "1a", "1a", NaN]})
```

I used `append` with `loc`

`df1 = df1.append(df2.loc[df2['pupil_mixed'] != df1['pupil'] ])`

which just appended the other column to the df with the matching row value and changed the non matching row values to NaN

```
    pupil   class   pupil_mixed
0   sarah   1a      NaN
1   john    1a      NaN
2   fred    1a      NaN
2   NaN     1a      lex
```

Comment: Why the class for lex is `NaN`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) + [drop_duplicates](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
res = pd.concat((df1, df2['pupil_mixed'].to_frame('pupil'))).drop_duplicates('pupil')

print(res)
```

**Output**

```
   pupil class
0  sarah    1a
1   john    1a
2   fred    1a
2    lex   NaN
```

As an alternative you could filter first (with [isin](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html)) and then concat:

```
# filter the rows in df2, rename the column pupil_mixed
filtered = df2.loc[~df2['pupil_mixed'].isin(df1['pupil'])]

# create a new single column DataFrame with the pupil column
res = pd.concat((df1, filtered['pupil_mixed'].to_frame('pupil')))

print(res)
```

Both solutions use [to_frame](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_frame.html), with the name parameter, effectively changing the *column* name.

Answer (score 0):

```py
# distinct df1 & df2
df1['tag'] = 1
df2['tag'] = 2

# change the column name the same
df2.columns = df1.columns
df1 = df1.append(df2)
# drop_duplicates by keep df1
df1 = df1.drop_duplicates('pupil', keep='first')

# set tag == 2, class is null
cond = df1['tag'] == 2
df1.loc[cond, 'class'] = np.nan
del df1['tag']

print(df1)
```

output:

```
print(df1)

   pupil class
0  sarah    1a
1   john    1a
2   fred    1a
3    lex   NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a merge, after renaming `pupil_mixed` in df2:

```
df1.merge(df2["pupil_mixed"].rename("pupil"), how="outer")

   pupil    class
0   sarah   1a
1   john    1a
2   fred    1a
3   lex    NaN
```